# Best way to install sass in create react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

What is the best way to install sass in create-react-app?
(npm run eject or node-sass-chokidar)

Can I please get some help? Thanks.

Comment: FYI since `react-scripts@2.0.0` all you need to do is install `node-sass` and import a file with the extension `.scss` or `.sass`. Much easier than in previous versions!

Comment: @HermanStarikov is right. Latest react version have sass loader by default.

Answer (score 6):

Best way is reading the document.

[Adding a CSS Preprocessor (Sass, Less etc.)](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet)

Comment: Why you would prefer node-sass-chokidar?

Comment: @Kurshith that question is also answered in the documentation (under "Why `node-sass-chokidar`?")

Answer (score 5):

You’ll need to eject your project if you haven’t already

```
npm run eject
```

**Install SASS**
The SASS precompiler runs at build time not runtime, therefore we save it with the save-dev switch

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev
```

Reference: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/how-to-add-sass-or-scss-to-create-react-app-c303dae4b5bc

Comment: You may want to eject to add sass support in CRA, but it is not mandatory and [can be done with minimal effort](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc).

Comment: I'm using create-react-app in version 2.1.1 and didn't have to modify my webpack.config file. I just ran npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev and it did the job.